# Magento 2.4 Error during upgrade: Schema binary is not declared

Tags: database, error, upgrade, magento2.4

When I run the setup:upgrade command I get the following error:

```
Cache cleared successfully
Schema creation/updates:
Types binary is not declared
```

The front end seems to work fine. I also found binary declaration in StringBinary.php so this type should be supported by Magento.
How can I find out which module/schema causes this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a manual way that you can disable the modules one by one and check again with the upgrade command.